# Erro na Tela de Login - Xamarin Forms Visual Studio 2017 Android

Tags: android, xamarin-forms, visual-studio-2017

Estou tendo dificuldade em buscar o conteúdo do Elemento `Entry` e comparar com o valor que está sendo armazenado no BD SQLite.

Segue o código da minha classe `Usuarios`:

```
public class Usuarios
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public long? usu_id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string usu_nome { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string usu_senha { get; set; }
}
```

Código da `ContentPage` `TelaLogin.xaml`:

```
<StackLayout Margin="10">
    <!--Aqui estamos inserindo o logotipo da empresa-->
    <Frame HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
           Padding="3" Margin="3">
        <Image Source="logo.jpg" />
    </Frame>
    <Label Text="Login" 
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
           FontSize="Large" TextColor="Cyan" Style="bold"/>
    <!--Aqui estamos buscando na tabela Usuarios, o Nome e a Senha-->
    <Entry x:Name="txtUsuario" 
           Placeholder="Usuário" 
           PlaceholderColor="Cyan" 
           Text="{Binding Usuario}" 
           TextColor="Cyan" 
           Style="bold"/>
    <Entry x:Name="txtSenha" 
           Placeholder="Senha" 
           PlaceholderColor="Cyan" 
           IsPassword="True" 
           Text="{Binding Senha}" 
           TextColor="Cyan" 
           Style="bold"/>
    <Button Text="Login" 
            Clicked="btnTelaLogin" />
    <Button Text="Tela Usuários" 
            Clicked="btnTelaUsuarios" 
            BackgroundColor="Orange" TextColor="White" />
</StackLayout>
```

Código da TelaLogin.xaml.cs:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class TelaLogin : ContentPage
{
    public TelaLogin ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        //remove a barra de navegação
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    }

    private async void btnTelaLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Usuarios login = new Usuarios();
        if (login.usu_nome != null && login.usu_nome != null)
        {                
            if(login.usu_nome ==  txtUsuario.Text && login.usu_senha == txtSenha.Text)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new TelaPrincipal());
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Erro", "Usuário ou Senha Estão Inválidos. Verifique !!!!", "OK");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Erro", "Usuário ou Senha Estão Vazios. Verifique as Caixas de texto !!!!", "OK");
        }            
    }

    private async void btnTelaUsuarios(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new TelaUsuarios());
    }
}
```

Não estou conseguindo fazer o teste na seguinte linha:

```
if(login.usu_nome ==  txtUsuario.Text && login.usu_senha == txtSenha.Text)
```

Não está reconhecendo o `txtusuario.Text` e o `txtSenha.Text`.

O cadastro de Usuário está funcionando.

Onde posso estar errando?

Grato por uma resposta, se possível.

Comment: Como você declarou esses nomes certinho no `Xaml`, deveria reconhecer. Pode ser algum problema de cache. Tenta excluir as pastas `bin` e `obj` do seu projeto, faz um clean e um rebuild. Avisa se o problema persistir

Comment: Obrigado epal ajuda Diego. Era isto mesmo, fiz a limpeza e os objetos foram reconhecido. Agora não estou conseguindo comparar o que é digitado na caixa de texto txtusuario e txtSenha, cm o valor que esta gravado no banco de dados, usu_nome e usu_senha, onde posso estar errando?

Comment: Vou postar como resposta para finalizar essa thread. A partir dai voce abre uma nova pergunta para a gente tratar especificamente essa comparação ai que mencionou.  Não ficou muito claro para mim

Answer (score 0):

Os únicos requisitos para você usar um elemento definido via `XAML` no codebehind são:

- Declarar a propriedade `x:Name` no elemento com o nome que será usado como variável
- Usar um nome único para cada elemento

Como você declarou esses nomes certinho no `Xaml`, deveria reconhecer, mas as vezes o Visual Studio e o Android tem alguns problemas com caching. Eu já vivenciei algumas situações dessas, mas não consegui determinar exatamente qual é o agente causador, mas a solução geralmente é uma das opções abaixo (ou a combinação delas):

**Visual Studio**

- Excluir as pastas `bin` e `obj` dos projetos da solução
- Fazer o <kbd>Clean</kbd> e <kbd>Rebuild</kbd> da solução
- Desmarcar a opção <kbd>Use Fast Deployment</kbd> do projeto android
- Desmarcar a opção <kbd>Use Shared Runtime</kbd> do projeto android

**Android**

- Desinstalar manualmente a versão anterior do aplicativo
- Desinstalar manualmente todos os aplicativos de debug instalados pelo visual studio (Mono Shared Runtime e Xamarin.Android API-XX Support)